# How to show a views count for nodes that ar not available to anonymous users

Tags: views, users

I made a view which displays a count for nodes in a nodetype. But anonymous users don't have access to nodes in that type. Those users should be able to view the count. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to edit screen of your view. In right column, *Advanced* section, click *Query settings*.
Check *Disable Query Rewritting*. Now Drupal permissions will not affect views results.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, Molot. Shame on me, i should have known this.

Comment: @caskraker no shame - everything is easy once you know it.